# Overflow-x:hidden; can still scroll when open at my phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I create a front end for my web site. It's fine open on my laptop browser.. and fine open on mobile mode on laptop browser.. after I upload it to hosting.. when I open it with my phone. The page can be scrolled to right.. but I am already making the overflow-x is hidden.

Please help me.

My hostess link is: https://punyagua2001.000webhostapp.com/bitlend/

Comment: We can't help much without looking at your code. Can you please share it with us?

Comment: What u need CSS code or html code ?

Comment: Depending on how you apply `overflow-x: hidden`, we need to look at your html/css/js. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: post your code or atleast post u r hosted website link

Comment: Ok. Give me a minutes

Comment: Check it sir. I am attach hostes link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the div.wrapper-circle, tat's the problem, some circle in this div cross the border

Comment: Greats !. Thank you sir 

Comment: Ah I'ts only working for mobile mode on chrome.. in real phone.. it's same

Comment: Any question now? How have you deal with the div.wrapper-circle or its children?

Comment: Now i am delete the .wrapper-circle and making the circle out of the div.. the circle position is absolute and the body overflow-x is hidden.

Comment: How can you cancel my answer→_→